# JS infinite loop protection, how to use babel-standalone plugins without node or web-worker with DOM?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, infinite-loop, web-worker

Have an in browser code-editor (ace) that compiles user-written code on the fly for p5.js. Researching how to prevent infinite loops and learned that a few such editors use [babel-standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone) together with [loop-protect](https://github.com/jsbin/loop-protect). To avoid issues with the timed loop flag (default 100ms), there's a plugin called [transform-prevent-infinite-loops.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/d906de7f602df810c38aa622c83023228b047db6/scripts/babel/transform-prevent-infinite-loops.js) used by [repl.it](https://repl.it) which instead limits number of iterations.

Both look great and want to test them out, but am failing to figure out how to use either (both CommonJS modules) with babel-standalone, particuarly when not using a bundler or nodejs. I was optomistic that there's a way to load these plugins directly, since I don't need my own code parsed, just analyze code waiting as a variable string. Got the inline [lolizer](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone#custom-plugins) plugin example working – but the above infinite loop protecting plugins are far more complex and unfortunately the docs don't seem to mention importing external plugins with stand-alone. Is it possible to use these without a bundler or nodejs?

Basic setup: https://pastebin.com/LEYx8Kr4

---

**Previously shared other attempts tried, but reducing to a single question as suggested.**

<del>Basic setup w/ web-worker: https://pastebin.com/NgAPZzCX</del>

<del>Also on the pastebin is an attempt using a [web-worker route](https://cwestblog.com/2016/03/16/javascript-detecting-infinite-loops/), however seems it doesn't support [DOM API](https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/how-to-detect-dead-loops-in-javascript.html), where p5.js functions are introduced. To solve this, tried doing some fancy regex to strip the code down to just the loops, but then you're missing variables, ie. if the loop count was `loopCount` instead of `10`.</del>

<del>Ultimate goal is getting a red flag if there's an infinite loop to prevent recompiling bad code that would overwrite what's currently running (live-coding environment). The web-worker route provided that and if I understand babel correctly, it wouldn't flag it, but actually changes the code being compiled to catch that infinite loop... is there yet another technique to consider or maybe a hybrid of it all?</del>

Comment: You seem to be asking multiple questions here and you also are asking opinion-based questions. Please focus on one question that is not opinion-based

Comment: FWIW, astexplorer uses `halting-problem`, which just needs access to the source code as string: https://github.com/fkling/astexplorer/blob/f92fcff9e4c5ec7d0f2a7ca229f47bbfdd97258a/website/src/parsers/utils/protectFromLoops.js . I think it has worked well enough so far.

Comment: @TheGrandJ thanks for advice, just reduced to singular issue.

Comment: @FelixKling added to pool of options to explore. `halting-problem` they use seems based on Acorn (I'm not fixed on babel but was leaning that way) – looks like a bundler would also be needed for that route.

Comment: What are you looking for? An implementation in a single file? What's with the "no-bundler" requirement? At the very least you could bundle any of those solutions *once* and include the file wherever you need it.

Comment: Exactly – as babel-standalone is offered as a single file, I am/was optomistic another single file could be included for attaching a plugin – that's it. Bundling/browserifying them once and including is an option, but the question is if that can be avoided?

Comment: Modified search terms turned up popcode's [loop-breaker](https://github.com/popcodeorg/loop-breaker) offering a browser-ready loop-protection. Question above still remains, but maybe it's simply 'you have to bundle for plugins'...

Comment: [loop-breaker](https://github.com/popcodeorg/loop-breaker) (implementing pending PR changes to break on either time delay or loop count) has turned out to be the best solution thus far- instantly catches infinte loops from common mistakes. Needed to be bundled once (as suggested above), but fortunately repo was setup as a project to be webpacked and used. Was anti having all of the modules in the main project using the script – but as external build worked well.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a repl for my library and am already using babel standalone.

This question was spot-on for me as it helped me to solve the issue using the linked babel plugin from react.

if you declare somewhere your plugin function

```
const preventInfiniteLoops = ({ types: t, template }) => {
  const buildGuard = template(`
    if (ITERATOR++ > MAX_ITERATIONS) {
      throw new RangeError(
        'Potential infinite loop: exceeded ' +
        MAX_ITERATIONS +
        ' iterations.'
      );
    }
  `)

  return {
    visitor: {
      'WhileStatement|ForStatement|DoWhileStatement': (path, file) => {
        // An iterator that is incremented with each iteration
        const iterator = path.scope.parent.generateUidIdentifier('loopIt')
        const iteratorInit = t.numericLiteral(0)
        path.scope.parent.push({
          id: iterator,
          init: iteratorInit,
        })
        // If statement and throw error if it matches our criteria
        const guard = buildGuard({
          ITERATOR: iterator,
          MAX_ITERATIONS: t.numericLiteral(MAX_SOURCE_ITERATIONS),
        })
        // No block statment e.g. `while (1) 1;`
        if (!path.get('body').isBlockStatement()) {
          const statement = path.get('body').node
          path.get('body').replaceWith(t.blockStatement([guard, statement]))
        } else {
          path.get('body').unshiftContainer('body', guard)
        }
      },
    },
  }
}
```

then it is simple to add it to babel standalone

update your pastebin example: (this is a guess, I have not tested it)

```js
Babel.availablePlugins['preventInfiniteLoops'] = preventInfiniteLoops
let output = Babel.transform(codeIn.value, { presets: [], plugins: ['preventInfiniteLoops']}).code;
```

I am using es6, so my code does it this way:

```js
import { availablePlugins } from '@babel/standalone'
availablePlugins['preventInfiniteLoops'] = preventInfiniteLoops
```

This post helped me immensely, hope my comment helps someone else too